# A #search action in a controller refuses to work and erroneously goes to #show

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a site-wide search form in my application.html.erb. Which is meant to go to the #search action in my controller. Instead, it perpetually attempts to go to #show. I've tried a bunch of hacks to understand why and they're all busts. Any guidance would be most appreciated.

Attempts:

- I stripped everything back to research, and just render plain: "OK"
  in the controller, going straight to the route in the browser and it
  still presents the #show action.
- I've restarted the server several times.
- Revised the `collect do syntax in routes.rb` to a one-line hardcoded route `get 'lists/search' => 'lists#search', as: 'search_lists'`
- Checked in the rails console to see if Searchkick works, `List.search "*"` returns the expected results
- I randomly put the `def search` in the application/controller, not sure why, but I thought I'd see if that did it.

application.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(url: search_lists_path , method: 'get', local: true) do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
  <%= submit_tag('Search') %>
<% end %>
```

search.html.erb

```
<%= content_tag(:h1, "Search Results") %>
<% @list.each do |list| %>
  <%= list.name %>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :lists
  resources :lists do
    collection do
      get 'search'
    end
    resources :products
    resources :comments
  end
  root 'lists#index'
end
```

controller

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController
    def search
        render plain: "OK"
    end
    def index
        @list = List.all
    end
    def show
        @list = List.find(params[:id])
    end
```

Excerpt from rails routes

> search_lists GET    /lists/search(.:format)                                                                  lists#search

Comment: Remove `resources :lists` before `resources :lists do`.

Comment: @MarekLipka amazing! thank you - worked the first time.